# Mercurial: Creating a diff of two commits

Tags: mercurial, diff

Is there a way to get the changes of two commits with mercurial?
The second commit is not directly after the first one, there are some other ones between them.

I tried

```
hg diff [some params] --change xxxxx --change yyyyy > file.patch
```

but that only includes the last changeset.

If there is no way to achieve this with hg, is there maybe a tool to combine patches?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I came upon this page while trying to figure this very thing out. I found my solution via `hg help diff` .

`hg diff -r <rev> -r <rev>` worked for my needs (diffing between two tags)

Comment: You can diff between any two revisions, they don't need to be tagged.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in case commits are not directly after one another. In this case it includes also everything between them, which is exactly what needs to be avoided.

Comment: I found the `--only-files-in-revs` flag useful with this when the codebase is large, to force `hg` to only look at files modified in the revisions (`hg diff -r <rev> -r <rev> --only-files-in-revs`).

Comment: Option --only-files-in-revs not available in Mercurial v5.7.1

Answer (score 6):

#### An external diff

The extdiff extension will allow you to use your preferred external diff tool.  In my case I use meld so day to day I run this type of command

`hg meld -r <rev1> -r <rev2>`

First enable the extdiff extension in the extensions section (I also have shelve & record enabled)

```
[extensions]
shelve =
record =
hgext.extdiff =
```

Then add this section ...

```
[extdiff]
cmd = meld
cmd.meld = /usr/bin/meld
```

to your .hgrc file. Obviously replace meld with the command used to launch your preferred tool

Comment: I think we should enable the extdiff extension first, so the whole .hgrc is `[extensions]
extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.extdiff = meld
`

Comment: @Asaka - Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 2):

Export? One patch-file per changeset, something like

`hg export --output %r.patch --rev A --rev B`